# PHP | Returns Invalid Links

Tags: php, html, file

So I have some PHP meant to read through a EVERYTHING in a directory (directories, sub directories, files, etc). This returns the proper list, but all of me links are 'invalid', but they're not. I can't click them or open them in a new window because it just goes to `about:blank`, but if I right-click then copy it, I can paste it and go to the valid webpage. I'm not too sure what would cause this. Here is my relevant code:
Example Output:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <ol>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/1.png">1.png</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/3.jpg">3.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/4.jpg">4.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/5.jpg">5.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/5x5_1.jpg">5x5_1.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/5x5_2.jpg">5x5_2.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/5x5_3.jpg">5x5_3.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/6.jpg">6.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/7.jpg">7.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/7a44d9dc51b3497ebe0f48be75c57e4d.png">7a44d9dc51b3497ebe0f48be75c57e4d.png</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/9.jpg">9.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title">Camera Roll
      <ol>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Camera Roll/desktop.ini">desktop.ini</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/IMG_00000001.jpg">IMG_00000001.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/IMG_00000002.jpg">IMG_00000002.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/IMG_00000003.jpg">IMG_00000003.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Image10.gif">Image10.gif</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Leedle.png">Leedle.png</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Music - Shortcut.lnk">Music - Shortcut.lnk</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title">Overwolf
      <ol></ol>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/STANK FACE.png">STANK FACE.png</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title">Saved Pictures
      <ol>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Saved Pictures/desktop.ini">desktop.ini</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="title">Screenshots
      <ol>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/1.png">1.png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/2.png">2.png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/3.png">3.png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/4.png">4.png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/5.png">5.png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (10).png">Screenshot (10).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (11).png">Screenshot (11).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (12).png">Screenshot (12).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (15).png">Screenshot (15).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (16).png">Screenshot (16).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (17).png">Screenshot (17).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (18).png">Screenshot (18).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (19).png">Screenshot (19).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (20).png">Screenshot (20).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (21).png">Screenshot (21).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (22).png">Screenshot (22).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (23).png">Screenshot (23).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (24).png">Screenshot (24).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (25).png">Screenshot (25).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (26).png">Screenshot (26).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (27).png">Screenshot (27).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (28).png">Screenshot (28).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (29).png">Screenshot (29).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (30).png">Screenshot (30).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (31).png">Screenshot (31).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (32).png">Screenshot (32).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (33).png">Screenshot (33).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (34).png">Screenshot (34).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (35).png">Screenshot (35).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (36).png">Screenshot (36).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (37).png">Screenshot (37).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (38).png">Screenshot (38).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (39).png">Screenshot (39).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (40).png">Screenshot (40).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (41).png">Screenshot (41).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (42).png">Screenshot (42).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (43).png">Screenshot (43).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (44).png">Screenshot (44).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (45).png">Screenshot (45).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (46).png">Screenshot (46).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (47).png">Screenshot (47).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (48).png">Screenshot (48).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (49).png">Screenshot (49).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (50).png">Screenshot (50).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (51).png">Screenshot (51).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (52).png">Screenshot (52).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (53).png">Screenshot (53).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (54).png">Screenshot (54).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (55).png">Screenshot (55).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (56).png">Screenshot (56).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (57).png">Screenshot (57).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (58).png">Screenshot (58).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (59).png">Screenshot (59).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (6).png">Screenshot (6).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (7).png">Screenshot (7).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (8).png">Screenshot (8).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot (9).png">Screenshot (9).png</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshots.rar">Screenshots.rar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/Thumbs.db">Thumbs.db</a>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Screenshots/desktop.ini">desktop.ini</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/Super_Smash_Bros_Melee_box_art.png">Super_Smash_Bros_Melee_box_art.png</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title">Uplay
      <ol></ol>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/WTF RED SAYS HE LOOKS LIKE HOUSE.png">WTF RED SAYS HE LOOKS LIKE HOUSE.png</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/X-Ray_1.jpg">X-Ray_1.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/X-Ray_2.jpg">X-Ray_2.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/X-Ray_3.jpg">X-Ray_3.jpg</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/desktop.ini">desktop.ini</a>
    </li>
    <li class="title">iCloud Photos
      <ol>
        <li class="title">Downloads
          <ol>
            <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/iCloud Photos/Downloads/desktop.ini">desktop.ini</a>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="title">Shared
          <ol>
            <li class="title">Album
              <ol></ol>
            </li>
            <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/iCloud Photos/Shared/desktop.ini">desktop.ini</a>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="title">Uploads
          <ol>
            <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/iCloud Photos/Uploads/[clips4sale.com]2015.02.08_PSBT&amp;GH.mp4">[clips4sale.com]2015.02.08_PSBT&amp;GH.mp4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/iCloud Photos/Uploads/[clips4sale.com]2015.03.03_ILYBRD.mp4">[clips4sale.com]2015.03.03_ILYBRD.mp4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/iCloud Photos/Uploads/[clips4sale.com]2015.08.19_AnalRed_FULL.mp4">[clips4sale.com]2015.08.19_AnalRed_FULL.mp4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/iCloud Photos/Uploads/[clips4sale.com]2015.08.19_AnalWhite_FULL.mp4">[clips4sale.com]2015.08.19_AnalWhite_FULL.mp4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/iCloud Photos/Uploads/[clips4sale.com]2015.10.12_ReadyAimFire_WMV_3000Kbps_720p.mp4">[clips4sale.com]2015.10.12_ReadyAimFire_WMV_3000Kbps_720p.mp4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/iCloud Photos/Uploads/desktop.ini">desktop.ini</a>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/iCloud Photos/desktop.ini">desktop.ini</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="title"><a href="C:\Users\Thatr\Pictures/kQRi9HT.png">kQRi9HT.png</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li class="title">';
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
                echo $ff;
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            }else{
                echo '<a href="'.$dir.'/'.$ff.'">'.$ff.'</a>';
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}


listFolderFiles(getcwd());
?>
```

Comment: Use URLs instead of real paths ! example, `http://localhost/path/file.ext` and create symlinks !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH is there any other way? I f I do it that way, I'd have to rewrite my code.

Comment: Try to add `file:///` to your URLs , example: `file:///C:/Users/Thatr/Pictures/6.jpg`

Comment: That's bad you need to use a server..! Install XAMPP on your PC or start using some online hosting server otherwise if you hardcode your own computer paths into your site..You are going to be in alot of trouble when you upload it online or when you want to open it somewhere else..! :D

Comment: Haha. I am currently using MAMP and I hate the style of the file listing so I decided to make my own. So all-in-all I DO have a server.

Comment: Sorry My bad...after all I forgot that PHP can't run without a server but still it made me curious why would you use your `file:///` protocol than using `http://` protocol to access assets of your site..!

Comment: I can do that easily, but it would require re-writing the entire code.

Comment: Well..as you wish and one thing more ofcourse you don't need to rewrite your whole code to do that..!

Comment: Haha. Alright if that's TRUELY the only way, then I'll get to it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** You seem to be missing the [**`file URI scheme (file:///)`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) in all of your links.

**Solution :**
Add proper protocol to the start of your URL's and you will be good to go as :

```
<a href="file:///C:/UsersThatr/Pictures/9.jpg">9.jpg</a>
```

**Note :** Use forward slash `/` for going deeper into directories in your links and also you shouldn't mix both slashes in links as because that's way it will also won't work then..!

> Credit Goes To [Ismail RBOUH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6431814/ismail-rbouh) For Pointing It Out First...!